# getElementsByTagName() and text inside .click

Tags: javascript, get, click, html-lists, element

I have clickable list elements, same class and role, and just text inside is different. I need to chose one and click same (text) li element all the time.
This function  `document.getElementsByTagName("li")[5].click()` works, but sometimes index change and pres wrong line. i have same value all the time like "222" but index may be different, how to .click not by tag name, but text?

```
<ul>
            <li>111</li>
            <li>222</li>
            <li>333</li>
            <li>444</li>
</ul>
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through *li* and check content of each one

```js
for (element in document.getElementsByTagName("li")) {
  if (element.textContent === '222') {
    element.click();
    break;
  }
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp

Or you can try to build querySelector. But I'm not sure if it supports content.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Thanks, I try the code to choose"All" but seems not working. and also read these topics you add, also try quesySelector but ether i using it wrong or not working :D  li fragment i need:`<ul class="x-list-plain"><li role="option" unselectable="on" class="x-boundlist-item">All</li></ul>`  bookmarlet i try `  javascript: (function () {   for (element in document.getElementsByTagName("li")) {  if (element.textContent === 'All') { element.click();    break;  }}`